# Iterate over play jsarray

Tags: scala, play-json

I am trying to iterate over play JsArray as below

```
    for (id <- myJSArray) {
      val bn = new Person(new IDM(id.asInstanceOf[String]))
      request.add(bn)
    }
```

but the above does not works with for each...error is cannot resolve symbol foreach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the `.value` method to access a container that will work with a for loop.

That said, there's hardly any reason to ever do that. Most things with Play-Json can be achieved in better ways. You would have to tell us more about what you're trying to do here – iterating over an array is not a goal, merely a means to an end.